# Xcode XCUItest LaunchTests - how do they work

Tags: xcode, xcuitest

If I create a new Xcode project with Xcode 14 with checked 'Include Tests' checkbox it creates 2 files in the UITests folder:

[image: testfiles]

I am interested in the second one: the [Project]LaunchTests.swift file.
There is this automatically generated code:

```
    func testLaunch() throws {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launch()

    // Insert steps here to perform after app launch but before taking a screenshot,
    // such as logging into a test account or navigating somewhere in the app

    let attachment = XCTAttachment(screenshot: app.screenshot())
    attachment.name = "Launch Screen"
    attachment.lifetime = .keepAlways
    add(attachment)
}
```

If I run this test from the diamond in the code, it runs 4 tests that I can view in the report navigator:

[image: run tests]

Xcode runs these 4 tests, but I didn't define them anywhere.
Question: where can I find the definition of that tests? Is this kind of an internal testplan which is associated with the LaunchTests file? Where can I find more information about this? It looks like there is a way to run tests with changing light/dark mode and changing orientation without writing a line of code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the four variants of the test to run, then do not (as the template does) return the `runsForEachTargetApplicationUIConfiguration` value for this test class as `true`.

As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/3867004-runsforeachtargetapplicationuico) tells you, when this is `true`, the test runner consults your actual app target to see what variants it has (light and dark mode, orientations, language localizations).

Comment: thanks once again! I completely overlooked that. And, this is exactly the behaviour that I was after and haven't found a nice solution yet.